# How do different operating systems have different window layouts?

Tags: windows, operating-systems, mac

I have searched on the Internet on how do operating systems have different window layouts, but I have found nothing. Windows has one style, Mac OS has another, and Linux has a different style as well. How are they able to have a different layout for the window. Below are two examples of window layouts. They are able to work the same way (open a window), but the way the top of the window looks like is different in the operating systems.
[image]

[image]

Edit:
The question has been answered

Comment: What do you mean by "window style" precisely?

Comment: Windows has a different way of how the window is designed unlike Linux and Mac OS @Jasmijm Also, animations of opening the window is different

Comment: Sorry but from my perspective your question doesn't make sense. It is like someone would ask how different books have different text layout. The answer is the same: because somebody did it this way.

Comment: Your question is probably off-topic here, but out of curiosity, can you clarify: why do you think they shouldn't be able to have different window styles/layouts? Go into a bit more depth - what about it makes you think this shouldn't work or be possible?

Comment: Do you mean one program? E.g. Word on Windows has one look, on Mac another, and on Linux a third?

Comment: This question either needs a lot more details, or is opinion-based, but I attempted an answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to be based on a false premise — that all OS vendors use common code or designs to create user interface elements. There is no general code library used by all operating system vendors, nor is there an international design standard.

Each vendor is free to design the user interface as they see fit. Companies are trying to make a profit, so appearing unique helps establish brand identity. This makes it easier for their customers to identify their product amongst all the competitors. Brand identity is used in almost all areas of a free market economy, not just software.

Since those companies want to look unique, and they spend tremendous amounts of money developing, promoting and distributing operating systems, they likely protect the look and feel of the OS with patents, copyrights, and trademarks. If a competitor uses their design, a company can sue in order to protect their brand identity.

Open source operating systems do not have the budget to pay lawyers, so open source projects will be designed different enough to avoid infringing on patents, copyrights, and trademarks.

Each vendor develops code independently. This alone means user interface elements will look and behave differently. When you factor in brand identity and lawsuits, every vendor tries to be different.

This, of course, doesn't stop companies from suing each other. It also doesn't stop them from using similar designs. Visual design and usability is a very big area of expertise, and is highly subjective. Like programming, best practices have been developed for UI designs. These are often described in very general terms, without regard to colors, textures, or fine grained details about behavior.